# Spring boot gives AbstractJdbcConfiguration errors on JUnit Test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Im trying to test my Repository with junit.

I have parent project Maven and some subproject for user activty.

this is parent pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.testpr</groupId>
    <artifactId>testprWebParent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>testprWebParent</name>
    <description>parent testpr web parent</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <modules>
        <module>testprBackEnd</module>
        <module>testprFrontEnd</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.testprcommon</groupId>
            <artifactId>testprCommon</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        
    </dependencies>
 
</project>
```

and this is a child or subproject pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.testpr</groupId>
        <artifactId>testprWebParent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>   
    </parent>
    <artifactId>testprBackEnd</artifactId>
    <name>testprBackEnd</name>
    <description>testpr Admin Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.30</version>
    </dependency>
    
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The child project is in the parent folder and also used  tag from parant project.

I made a test class in child project inside eclipse and if i run Junit it gives me this

error :

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/jdbc/repository/config/AbstractJdbcConfiguration .....

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey kinda confusing error log but after i change my test class from this

```
@DataJdbcTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
public class RoleRepositoryTests {
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository repo;
    
    @Test
    public void testCreateFirstRole() {
        Role roleAdmin = new Role("Admin","For Test");
        Role savedRole = repo.save(roleAdmin);
        assertThat(savedRole.getId()).isGreaterThan(0);
    }
}
```

to

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
public class RoleRepositoryTests {
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository repo;
    
    @Test
    public void testCreateFirstRole() {
        Role roleAdmin = new Role("Admin","For Test");
        Role savedRole = repo.save(roleAdmin);
        assertThat(savedRole.getId()).isGreaterThan(0);
    }
}
```

And my application.properties from this :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

to this :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Junit Test Runs Successfully.